# Download and installation of LaTex for Linux Ubuntu

Tags: installing, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu and I want to download and install LaTeX, what should I choose and where can I find it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092 would be my suggestion

Comment: I was just trying to get "Knit to PDF" working in RStudio for a RMD file, I ran the command in HATEthePLOT's answer and had to add: `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest way in ubuntu is to use the ubuntu package manager (from the desktop) and install the texlive package. As an editor you can choose whatever you want (texmaker, texstudio or any editor like gedit, vim and so on).
Alternatively, you can use the terminal to install the packages, using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive texstudio
```

Dependencies usually are matched automatically

edit: look for the ubuntu software-center to open the package manager GUI and search for the texlive and other packages.

If you want the latest texlive version, follow these instructions:
[texlive quick install](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)

Comment: Depending on the user's needs he will need also a package providing support for his language, and perhaps others that aren't included in the standard packages and their dependencies. I'd rather recommend installing **"`texlive-full`"**, although he probably will not use all the included features.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, does the texlive package not install according to the locale settings of the ubuntu (linux) distribution? I had the feeling it does.

Comment: I don't think so. I've just tried `apt-cache showpkg texlive` on a recent ubuntu distribution and it gives me only 3 dependencies: `texlive-latex-base`, `texlive-fonts-recommended`and `texlive-latex-recommended`, which in turn don't depend on any localization packages. This is understandable, because perhaps you want to use TeX to typeset material in a veriety of languages, not necessary your own's, and then you have to manually select which do you want to install.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the information. I myself don't use the ubuntu repo packages. However, since the thread starter seems to be new to ubuntu and latex I figured this would be the easiest way to get started.

Comment: If you are just trying to Knit to PDF in RStudio do this answer and then run `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` (worked for me YMMV), if you only run the command in the answer (`sudo apt-get install texlive texstudio`) you will likely get some missing file errors